# Get List of All Regional Setting Formats in .net

Tags: windows, vb.net, winapi

Within Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options, there is a Formats tab, with a drop down of all possible language formats. I wish to retrieve this list using VB.NET. Could anyone point in the direction of which Windows API call to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)`? Returns an array with all available cultures. No need for Windows API. Have a look at the other CultureTypes values to filter the culture list.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on the System.globalization.CultureInfo class in .net framework.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Answer from 2023: Make sure to use .NET Framework if you're looking for Windows regional formats, not .NET Core/.NET.

One example of the potential differences:

- Long date format for 'ja-JP' in .NET 7: `yyyy年M月d日dddd`
- Long date format for 'ja-JP' in **Windows** and .NET Framework: `yyyy'年'M'月'd'日'`

Other than that clarification, previous answers are correct.

Sample code to catch'em all, using [LINQPad 5](https://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx) to make sure .NET Framework is used underneath:

```cs
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Select(ci => ci.Name)
    .Select(cu => new
    {
        Culture = cu,
        LongDateFormat = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cu).DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern,
        ShortDateFormat = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cu).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
    })
    .Dump();
```